# Server Components' to be rendered data stays stand still at a script tag (Next.js - self.__next_f.push

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-server-components

I have the following [page.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxXPP.png).(Recall that I'm using Next.js app router.)

`<PageWithComments />` is a client component, and `<BlogPostContent />` is a server component.

For some reason, `<BlogPostContent />`'s to be rendered data keep remained in a script tag but never being put in actual html nodes and its not getting rendered.

- `<BlogPostContent />`'s [content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVkvi.png)
- The actual html looks like in the browser [devtools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDX6Z.png)
- Parent component `<PageWithComments />` 's content

```
const PageWithComments = ({ BlogpostContent = () => <></> }) => {
  useEffect(() ... //etc


  return (
    <div className={styles.blogPage}> />
      <BlogpostContent />
.
.
.
```

- Tried to disable dangerouslySetInnerHTML, thought it could cause some problems but it isn't the case.

```
<div
       className={styles.blogPostContent}
       dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: marked(text) }}
     ></div>
```